# What does the construct "const increment = ()();" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with this example of Javascript code:

```
    const real_numbers_array = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

        //Karkoli že je increment, sedaj postane funkcija.
        const increment = (
            function(){
                //Namesto zgornjega "function()" dobimo "increment" 
                return function increment (a1,a2 = 1){
                    return a1 + a2;
                }

        })(); 
        console.log(increment(5,2));
        console.log(increment(5));
```

Where we have a constant `increment` to which we assign an anonymous function `function()` which returns function `increment()` with two arguments of which second has a default value and those two arguments are summed up.

So far I understand this. But at the end there is `})();` and I don't know what is the meaning of the last empty `()`.

By default this code returns this:

[image]

And if I omit the `()` I get:

[image]

So what is the point of `()` at the end? Does anonymous function `function()` actually return only `increment` and we add `()` to get `increment()`. If this is so, why doesn't anonymous function return function as `increment()`. This is a default notation for functions afterall...

Is this some sort of an arrow function treachery? =)

Comment: It is a IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) it runs as soon as it's defined. `()` it creates a function expression through Javascript engine interpret the function and returns the output.

Comment: this question provided the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript
but I also don't know why this functions requires it, I don't think it is necessary in this particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

The function expression `()` at the end will ***immediately*** invoked the function through which the JavaScript engine will directly interpret the function.

Comment: Thank you very much for a fast response.

Comment: @71GA, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const num1 = 1, num2 = 2;

const calculateSum = (function (n1, n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
})(num1, num2);

console.log(calculateSum); // 3
```

You can pass arguments to the function expression inside `()`.